# Assign "Ctrl+S" to Subversion commit

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

In NetBeans, how can I make it so that every time I save a file it gets committed to Subversion?

Comment: Do you really want to commit changes before it was possible to run your test suite against them?

Comment: Yes, because i test on remote server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This sounds like a recipe for disaster!**

That being said . . .

1. Go to **Tools : Options** in the menu.
2. Go to the **Keymap** tab.
3. Type `commit` in the **Search** box.
4. Locate the row for "Commit..." / "Subversion".
5. Double-click in its **Shortcut** cell.
6. Press the desired shortcut (e.g. **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S**).
7. Click the **OK** button.

As committing a file automatically saves it first, you *could* use **Ctrl + S** as the shortcut if you wish.

Note that this also works when you select one or more files in the **Projects** pane. Thanks for asking the question as I get really sick of navigating through the popup menus all the time. :)

Comment: i set ALT+S for commit but it doesnt' work.
I tried to set Alt+S for other command and it work as well. What's the problem with "commit"?
If i assing ALT+S to "Subversion", NetBeans open a dialon on footer but it doesn't make the commit

Comment: @Leonardo - It works for me on Windows XP, but I had to add **Ctrl** because **Alt + S** brings down the **Source** menu. Is your project set up for SVN? Can you commit files through the popup menu?

Comment: @Leonardo - When you hit the commit key, it should open a dialog for you to enter the commit message and select which files to commit. When in the editor window, the only file should be the file in that window. When in the Project pane, all files selected should be listed. What exactly is happening?