# NetBeans & Git: shortcut for pushing to remote

Tags: git, netbeans, push, shortcut

I'm looking for a fast way to push my committed changes in NetBeans to the remote server. Currently this is a much too long path (navigate to Team > Remote > Push, click Next in dialog, check desired branch, click Next, click Finish). All this slows down the pushing process and should be doable in 1 click.

I've already seen a similar question concerning the committing: [Assign "Ctrl+S" to Subversion commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033755/assign-ctrls-to-subversion-commit)

Any ideas for the pushing process? For sure it would also be good to have something for the pulling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At Tools|Options|KeyMap you can set a shortcut for the action.

NB 7.4 will also allow you to put such common action to the toolbar - see http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB74#Versioning

Comment: Not 100% what I'm looking for but better than nothing :-)

Comment: @jor: What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the Git Toolbar plugin in older NetBeans releases.

In NetBeans 12 LTS, you don't have to install the Git Toolbar, it's integrated.
Just activate it by a right click on the toolbar and selecting **Git**.

Answer (score 0):

Look for "Push to Upstream" in the KeyMap, and set it to your key preference.